# SNMP error with port already in use

Tags: java, port, snmp

I have created a SNMP agent simulator application which use the port number 161 for the simulated devices. sometimes it occurs the port alredy in use exception. how can i know if the 161 port is busy or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using **netstat** command.

Specifically,

> netstat -s [PORT_NO]

For example,

> netstat -s 161

1. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/list-open-ports-and-listening-services/443
2. http://www.speedguide.net/faq_in_q.php?qid=115

Answer (score 2):

By just starting your application. If it gets a BindException, the port is in use. If it doesn't, your application can run. Knowing that ahead of time doesn't really buy you anything.

Comment: That's not always true. Port binding may be unsuccessful due to many reasons, not only because port is already in use. To be sure what went wrong, check the error message in java BindException, or errno value in C/C++ application (after bind call).

Answer (score 1):

Just additional remark. I think you may be forbidden to use low port numbers (security policy if not a root user) - try using higher numbers i.e. 10161.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use `netstat` and `tasklist`. For example,

```
netstat -aon | findstr 161
```

Its output should be

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>netstat -aon |findstr 161
  UDP    0.0.0.0:161            *:*                                    1620
  UDP    [::]:161               *:*                                    1620
```

Then use `tasklist`

```
tasklist /fi "PID eq 1620"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
snmp.exe                      1620 Services                   0      1,172 K
```

In my case obviously it is Windows SNMP services who uses port 161. In your case, it may be another process.

Answer (score 0):

```
1)ps -efww | grep 161   

2)netstat -anp | grep 161
```

Answer (score 0):

following statement works for me.

```
netstat -lnp
```

**sample usage:**

```
appuser@-app:~$ sudo netstat -lnp |grep 162
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1162/mysqld
udp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:162           :::*                                6830/java
```