# How can I get my Application bound to port 161?

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I'm working on a Java Project where I need to Simulate a Printer. Clients of the Printer send SNMP messages to the Printer.  Printer should have SNMP Agent running on port 161. Since, port 161 is a well known port, I'm unable to use that port. How can I get my Application bound to port 161?

Comment: relevant similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739768/snmp-error-with-port-already-in-use

Comment: what error do you get when you try to bind to port 161?

Comment: You can bind to any port and then use firewall to do portforwarding from port 161

Comment: @rkosegi, can you explain how to do portforwarding using firewall?

Comment: @vineethkumar : that would highly depend on OS you are using

Comment: And on the particular router. Usually you just enter the router configuration and add a port forwarding rule. Trigger port `161` (traffic comes to port `161`) and then let the router forward the traffic to a different port `X` and from there to your app which listens to that port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not because this is a well known port but because it is a reserved port (lower than 1024). On many operating systems, reserved ports can be bound by the superuser. So just run your java VM as root.

Comment: On some OSes the security manager might allow users to use reserved ports.